# c# control of ip webcam

Tags: c#, user-interface, webcam, packet-sniffers, hardware-interface

I recently purchased a cheap pan/tilt webcam, the camera is pretty cool but the interface leaves alot to be desired.

Its all web based but I was hoping to make a winform application so I can fit it a little better to my needs. (bind directions to arrow keys, remove some of the engrish)

my question is how can I capture the comands that are being sent via the web interface and then reproduce it in c#

Answer (score 4):

If you can't get hold of the API-documentation, you could try to sniff packets sent to the camera using e.g. wireshark. Hopefully the commands are sent in clear text.

There is a API-standard for networked cameras called Onvif, if you're lucky the camera conforms with that standard.

Comment: I'm not even sure what the company that makes it is. If I were sniffing the network what type of packets would i be looking for?

Comment: Start looking for HTTP-traffic. If it is a "passive" web-interface that would be the protocol used. If it installs some active component (Active X or similar) you could look for RTSP as well.

Comment: It has both a active x and a webonly interface